# System V MQ Text Length Issue

Tags: message-queue, arrays

I'm trying to write simple chat app with system v mqs but I am having a problem with my mtext value in the struct.

```
struct join_buf {
  long mtype;
  char mtext[8];
};
```

when I sent a message with this struct inserted. I is written in server sometimes correct and sometimes wrong. What I see is that; the number of the chars is fullfilled to 8.

What could you recommend me to read the mtext correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the mistake I am doing.

```
for (i = 0; i < nameLength; i++) {
         joinbuf.mtext[i]=argv[1][i];
    }
    joinbuf.mtext[i]='\0';
```

without the last line the end of string is the length of the char array. adding that I am telling the runtime that this is it! Not one bit more!